# matlab delete streaks of blanks from string

Tags: matlab, formatting

How can I delete streaks of blanks from a string?

When I have

```
i   hate  extra blanks     in my strings!
```

I want

```
i hate extra blanks in my strings!
```

I have found a solution

```
v(find(filter([1 1], 2, v == ' ') == 1)) = []
```

but I don't understand how it works (I tried to read this http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/data_analysis/filtering-data.html#bqm3i7m-3). Is there a simpler solution or can somebody please explain the above solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v(strfind(v, '  ')) = []
```

Will kill all blanks except single ones or the last blank in a streak of blanks.

Answer (score 3):

An even simpler REGEX:

```
>> str = 'i   hate  extra blanks     in my strings!';
>> regexprep(str, '\s+', ' ')
ans =
i hate extra blanks in my strings!
```

Comment: This function regexprep is not available in my matlab version it seems.

Comment: what version are you running? I can see it as far back as [R13sp2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R13sp2/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html) (which is from over 10 years ago!)

Comment: My mistake, I have the function. Your solution is good too and I will give you a vote as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be using [***`regexp`***](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

```
>> v='i   hate  extra blanks     in my strings!';
>> p=regexp(v, '\s+', 'split');    % Split Using regex pattern more or more space
>> [p{1} sprintf(' %s', p{2:end})] % Form the new array of chars

ans =

i hate extra blanks in my strings!
```

With new R2013a's *[**`strjoin`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html)*, you should be able to do

```
strjoin(p, ' '); % instead of last step
```

Answer (score 2):

There are MATLAB functions (`strtrim`, `deblank`, etc.) for removing additional blanks from the front or end of strings, but as far as I know no inbuilt for collapsing additional spaces from the centre. Since we've already got some `regexp` going on, I'll do the explanation of the code you already found:

Let's look at the `filter` part of your example to start.  `filter` works on numbers, not strings, so the `v == ' '` simply converts your string to a series of numbers where `1` is a space and `0` is anything not a space.  We can run this part separately to see what it does:

```
v2 =  filter([1 1], 2, v == ' ');
```

The filter itself is basically taking the average of two adjacent values (`[1 1]/2`), right through the string.  This will leave you with `1`s where you have a space with another space right before it, and 0 or 0.5 where you have a space with a letter right before it.  So only the extra spaces will return `1` in the filter.

The code wrapping around the code says "find where the filter returns one, and replace those parts of the string with empty" (e.g. remove them).  Actually the `find` is not required, you could do this directly with logical indexing:

```
v(filter([1 1], 2, v == ' ') == 1) = [];
```

Another improvement would be to use `isspace` rather than `v == ' '`, as this will capture more types of blank (e.g. `isspace` hits tabs and other things which aren't `' '`).

```
v(filter([1 1], 2, isspace(v)) == 1) = [];
```

Logical indexing + `= [];` is a quite common way in MATLAB to strip out unwanted data of various types. You do have to be cautious in cases where this will reshape your data - e.g. if you do this your originally square matrix becomes a vector:

```
x = randi(10,[5 5]); % outputs a 5 x 5 matrix
x(x==5)=[]; % output will be 1 x n
```

Comment: +1 for the good explanation of the filter solution. It seems overly tricky to me though.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be my first choice (I like your `strfind` suggestion) but `filter` is some people's favourite MATLAB hammer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I cannot vote yet but I will once I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the *dumbness* of it:

```
>>v='i   hate  extra blanks     in my strings!';
>>while(~strcmp(v, strrep(v, '  ',' '))), v=strrep(v,'  ',' '); end;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   v = 'i love wasting processor cycles!';
>>v

v =

i love wasting processor cycles!
```

I feel it should belong to codeboxing, though... :-)